# HTML5 Canvas Generator

Tags: html, canvas

is there any tool either online or software that can export as canvas code?

For example I drag some boxes or circles, add some colours and hit 'export' and my drawing is exported as canvas?

Comment: Are you trying to save an image of the drawing you created on the canvas?  If so try this:  var win=window.open();
        win.document.write("<img src='"+canvas.toDataURL()+"'/>"); If you're trying to serialize the canvas drawings and the drags, you'll have to build your own combination of JS and a data file containing the shape definitions and drag positions.

Answer (score 3):

There are not any tools that I know of that can do this. But you can always make your own.

Depending on your need -

### Recorder

If you want to replicate all the actions you can go with a recorder -

Create wrappers for the different methods you want to utilize and record their steps when you drag shapes etc. onto the canvas. For special actions such as moving an existing object to for instance a new location you would need to create custom actions for this. But in principle you could do something like this:

```
var stack = [];

function myMoveTo(x, y) {
    ctx.moveTo(x, y);
    stack.push({op: 'moveto', x: x, y: y});
}

function myLineTo(x, y) {
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    stack.push({op: 'lineto', x: x, y: y});
}

... etc.
```

Now your `stack` array contains all the operations you performed and you can simply iterate through them and generate JavaScript code from it (or SVG, redraw the canvas or convert it to a script for a different language and so forth).

```
var code = '  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");\n';

for(var i = 0, o; o = stack[i]; i++) {

    /// check what operation this object did
    switch(o.op) {

        case 'moveto':
            code += ' ctx.moveTo(' + o.x + ', ' + o.y + ');\n';
            break;

        case 'lineto':
            code += ' ctx.lineTo(' + o.x + ', ' + o.y + ');\n';
            break;

        ...
    }
}
```

Your `code` variable now contains JavaScript code you can paste into another project to replicate the drawings you did with your canvas.

## Converter

In case you don't want to replicate every action you can instead go with a converter approach that takes a "snapshot" of current state of canvas (which is what I suspect you're really asking for) -

You simply draw and store the objects themselves that you have on the canvas. You will need to create and define those object with its positions, size, color and so forth.

Then when you hit export you convert those objects using a similar approach as as above but instead of replicating each step of the actions you just convert the graphical objects themselves with the current state:

```
/// object also stored in a stack but represents the graphics not the action
var myObject = {type:'line', x1:10, y1:20, x2:70, y2:100, color:'#f70'};
stack.push(myObject);
```

And when you iterate:

```
...
case 'line';
    code += 'ctx.beginPath();\n';
    code += 'ctx.moveTo(' + o.x1 + ', ' + o.y1 + ');\n';
    code += 'ctx.lineTo(' + o.x2 + ', ' + o.y2 + ');\n';
    code += 'ctx.strokeStyle = "' + o.color + '";\n';
    code += 'ctx.stroke();\n';
...
```

### Convert to image

If you simply mean "as an image" you do:

```
var dataUri = canvas.toDataURL();
```

which you can use as a source for an image tag or upload to server:

```
var img = new Image;
img.src = dataUri;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Canvas is a HTML element, not a 'type' of file. You render graphics output to a canvas rather than loading a canvas explicitly.

What you could do is export to SVG (Scalable Vector Graphics) format then embed your .svg file into your HTML.

```
<embed src="filename.svg" type="image/svg+xml" />
```

Answer (score 0):

canvas code is basically an api written in javascript. What best you can do is bundle your code in a function and save the file as canvascode.js

```
function foo(context){
   // your canvas code
}
```

include it in your html file...whenever you need them just call this function by passing the canvas context parameter.

Comment: You misunderstood the question. The OP is looking for a drawing tool that would generate the "your canvas code" part for him.

Answer (score 0):

Old question: but there are some tools.... these are specifically online tools. I don't know about any software, but I'm sure there is.

Info courtesy of codetools.net ([http://www.codetools.net/online-tools/html5-canvas-generators](https://web.archive.org/web/20150227003508/http://www.codetools.net/online-tools/html5-canvas-generators))

Search for:
HTML5  bezierCurveTo Command Generator

This is a tool to generate calls to toBezierTool via a bezier path drawing GUI. It is intended for people who already know JavaScript/canvas and want to draw a simple non-standard shape, but don't want to fiddle with pixel values.

OR:
Canvas Designer

A tool aimed to give you a full-fledged drawing surface and also auto generate appropriate code for you in different formats. It targets Canvas 2D Context, i.e. it gives you a built-in IDE for Canvas 2D APIs.

OR:
Patternizer

With Patternizer, it’s easy to make something amazing in just a few minutes. It takes all the work out of creating complicated patterns, letting you focus on creativity and play. Patterns can be saved and shared with anyone, allowing for collaboration and remixing. And you can access them from any device worldwide. Patternizer generates code that can be used with patternizer.js to create these patterns on any  element. Patternizer patterns don’t use any images and only require a single tiny script. In many cases patternizer will be smaller than an image-based solution (if it’s even possible with an image).

Comment: This link is spam.